# R How to remove "INFO: Remember to close the consumer after done reading messages" when calling rkafka.read

Tags: r, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, rkafka

I am currently using R's package for kafka - rkafka. Every time I read from Kafka, I get "INFO: Remember to close the consumer after done reading messages". How do I avoid that?

```
>library(rkafka)
>consumer<-rkafka.createConsumer("1.2.3.4:2181","Real-time-data", consumerTimeoutMs = "-1")
>rkafka.read(consumer)
[1] "INFO: Remember to close the consumer after done reading messages"
{\"type\":\"activity_log\",\"id\":0,\"group\":\"prod\",\"screen\":null,\"event\":null,\"time\":\"19:25:00\",\"region\":2657896}"
```

Comment: Did you found another solution? I could be interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want capture the INFO message you can use the "capture.output" command:

```
capture.output(rkafka.read(consumer))
```

You can put the message in a variable and then discard it, like this:

```
info_msg<-capture.output(rkafka.read(consumer)) 
rm(info_msg)
```